# jQuery Mobile Windows Store App: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am porting an existing app to the new windows-plattform in Cordova. Or am trying. My problem now is, that while jquery runs fine - thanks to winstore.js - I always get a jquery Mobile error.

```
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference
```

This leads to a crash of my app, which is kind of annoying, because this error is not mine and on the old wp8-platform it was running just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [winstore-jscompat.js](https://github.com/MsopenTech/winstore-jscompat), try adding it after adding jQuery mobile.

I added jQuery first, then jQuery Mobile and then winstore-jscompat.js.